# android can not connect to MySql

Tags: android, mysql

When I connect to MySQL in android：
code show as below

```
protected static void connMysql(){
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    ResultSet res = null;
    String openurl_mysql="jdbc:mysql://10.15.26.21:3306/etrack_user&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false";
    try {
        java.sql.Driver.class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(openurl_mysql,"etrack","_etrack_mysql_");
        pstm = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) as count from et_patrol_task");
        res = pstm.executeQuery();
        while(res.next()){
            int count = res.getInt("count");
            System.out.println("return success=============="+count);
        }
        res.close();
        pstm.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run the program，I get the following problem:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1pvX.png)

[image]
Has anyone encountered a similar problem or solved it?

Comment: If you want to connect `Android` to `MySQL`, you should use third party - `PHP`

Comment: @Zack You shouldn't connect the DB directly from android (or any other client). There are many reasons for that, the most important (in my opinion) is security. Your android app should connect to a remote server - which (after authentication) would connect the DB, take the needed data and then return it to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a MySQL DB from Android natively.Actually you may be able to use JDBC, but it is not recommended.
JDBC is infrequently used on Android, and I certainly would not recommend it.

IMHO, JDBC is designed for high-bandwidth, low-latency, highly-reliable network connections (e.g., desktop to database server, Web application server to database server). Mobile devices offer little of these, and none of them consistently.